# How many periods of a periodic signal are required to properly determine magnitude?

Tags: dsp, sampling, fft

I have a pure sinusoidal test function. I am trying to determine the magnitude of the response through my circuit very soon after powering up with circuit. If  I am using a 1kHz test signal, I only get 1 period after 1ms. I am using an oscilloscope with a very high sampling rate (>1 GHz). It seems to me that by using an FFT, I should be able to get valid magnitude data after at least 1 ms. I know that averaging over more periods will reduce the noise, but I already have a sufficiently high enough SNR to not need to worry too much about noise.

Am I mistaken that I can get the true magnitude of my response using only 1 period?

Comment: It depends on the SNR. With no noise, you should be able to get it in a fraction of a period. "How" is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 4):

> I have a pure sinusoidal test function.
>
> I already have a sufficiently high enough SNR to not need to worry too
>   much about noise

If you know the frequency (as you say you do), then any fractional part of the sine wave can be analysed to give you the peak and RMS values of that pure sine wave. It's all in the math.

No fractional part of a sine wave with amplitude X can be mistaken for a fractional part of another sine wave (amplitude Y) unless Y = X.

This means if noise is really low you can predict the amplitude from a few microseconds worth of signal.

Think what happens when the sine wave passes through zero - if you measured the slope it can tell you the amplitude because: -

\$\dfrac{d(A\cdot Sin (\omega t))}{dt} = \omega A\cdot Cos(\omega t)\$

Comment: Ha, that's clever.